# Impressão de gráfico TeeChat no Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi-xe5, gráfico

Preciso imprimir um gráfico TeeChart no Delphi, mas ele fica totalmente desconfigurado quando a opção Smooth está desmarcada.

Este é o gráfico que deveria ser impresso:

[image: Imagem 1]

Na tela de impressão tem essa opção **Smooth** que não importa como eu configure ela não vem marcada automaticamente:

[image: Imagem 2]

Se eu não marcar a opção **Smooth** o gráfico é impresso desse jeito:

[image: Imagem 3]

Bom, eu quero saber pelo menos como eu faço pra essa opção já vir marcada. Eu já tentei configurar ela clicando com botão direito em cima do gráfico e indo em **Edit Chart**. As opções **Proportional** e **Background** vem marcadas mas a **Smooth** não.

Via código eu consegui achar como configurar o **Proportional** mas não achei o **Smooth**.

```
Grafico1.PrintProportional := True;
```